# Google storage Service account authentication requires PyOpenSSL after some time

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, pyopenssl

I use google storage via the python [boto plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcs-oauth2-boto-plugin/issues/26)

My python scripts **works as expected for about an hour or so**. Then it gives me the error:

```
Service account authentication requires PyOpenSSL. Please install this library and try again.
```

My code:

```
import boto

src_uri = boto.storage_uri(DOGS_BUCKET + '/' + filename, GOOGLE_STORAGE)
object_contents = StringIO.StringIO()
src_uri.get_key().get_file(object_contents)
```

pyopenssl is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem was caused by a too old python version

I don't have these problems with python 2.7.9+